# redirection on a e-commerce store checkout

Tags: php, redirect, e-commerce, payment, checkout

I need a solution (probably php).

I need a fast redirection from
mainsite.com/checkout to newsite/checkout.com

EXAMPLE:
Buyer purchase a service on mainsite.com and adds items and checkout. After chooseing the payment method and clicking on ''place order'', I want to have a redirection (in milliseconds) to newsite.com/checkout with the same data added (USD amount of the mainsite cart/checkout, and give the purchase a general name like ''JM Service Fee'')

Customer completes the payment (on the processor). and it goes back to newsite.com/checkout and in milliseconds back to mainsite.com confirming the order.

Hope you understand it.

Pls help what can I do?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

In php, you can use `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`, if you want a backend redirection.